# React hook useSelector value not changed inside async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, getstate

I've been using React Hook with useSelector and useDispatch for a while, mostly it works very well but recently I've experienced some very wired scenario. For example

```
// parentComponent
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const hasChanged = useSelector(state => {
    const isChanged = checkIfChanged(state);
    console.log('useSelector isChanged:>> ', isChanged);
    return isChanged;
  });

  const selectChange = async(userId, userCode)=> {
    console.log('selectChange hasChanged :>> ', hasChanged);
    // ...
  }
  return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent onSelectChange={selectChange} />
      </div>
  );
}
```

I have my properties saved in the state and whenever there is anything changed in my component, my `hasChanged` from `useSelector` will become **true**, however, when I made a change, I can see my `hasChanged` already become **true** in the `useSelector`, but still **false** inside my function `selectChange`!

```
console log
useSelector isChanged:>> true
useSelector isChanged:>> true
selectChange hasChanged :>> false // why it's false here as already true from useSelector
useSelector isChanged:>> true
```

Does anyone have the same experience? I am wondering if it's because my `selectChanged` is async-await so the value inside will not fetch from the latest state?

Comment: I think it's one of [zalgo being released](https://blog.izs.me/2013/08/designing-apis-for-asynchrony/) cases. If you think, `selectChange` is async, so it will return instantly and program will move on, in true `async` fashion. But the rest of the program is sync! You can't casually mix up sync and async — consider every single function and match the "cadence" of sync-ones to async-ones. Also, to enable caching, `useSelector` function has to be declared outside the component declaration, see https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use useEffect();

```
const {userId, userCode} = useSelector(state => { /* ... */ });
```

```
const selectChange = async () => {
    if (hasChanged) {
      await dispatch(notifyUser(userId, userCode));
    } else {
      await dispatch(redirectPage(userCode));
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    selectChange();
}, [hasChanged]);
```

```
return (
   <div>
       <Select />
   </div>
);
```

Comment: Well, that might not work because my `selectChange(userId, userCode)` is actually a callback from my my child component, which it would set the input parameter there...

Comment: I think you should store the input variables in the global state.

Comment: did you figure it out? I'm facing the same issue!